# Constant Y axis with raycast hit bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to fix up some bugs in my project and I've come across a problem with a mechanic where I want an object to move to my mouse cursor on click and stay 3 units above where I clicked.

Here is my code:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            var newPosition = hit.point;
            currentDestination = newPosition + new Vector3(0, 3.0f, 0);//mainly this
            notAtDestinationYet = true; 
        }
    }
```

However by using raycasts, If I hit anything above my terrain like the top of a building or something, the object with this script attached will always move 3 units above where the raycast hits.

How do I make it stay at a constant Y-Axis value of 3 units (or whatever amount) no matter what? Say by using a `public int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the line where you set the `currentDestination` to use the x and z values from `newPosition` and a constant y value, instead of adding 3f to the y value of `newPosition`.

```
currentDestination = new Vector3(newPosition.x, 3.0f, newPosition.z);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this do the-same thing as `currentDestination = newPosition + new Vector3(0, 3.0f, 0);` in OP's question?

Comment: @Programmer No because now we aren't adding 3 onto the y value of newPosition. My understanding of the problem was that the y value is 3 above where the raycast hit, whereas it should just be a hard coded 3.

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: Wow, just needed 1 line of code haha. Thank you so much for answering! Really would of stumped me if it wasn't for you two. Enjoy the week :)